# Heroku not able to find the worker

Tags: java, maven, heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku

I followed the above tutorial to deploy my app on heroku. When i package the code in my IDE (intelliJ IDEA) everything works fine. A target folder is created that has a sub floder named bin and it contains two files : worker and worker.bat

From my root director, if i run the command `sh target/bin/worker` then the application executes properly and desired.

On the otherhand after i push the code to heroku and use the command :

`heroku ps:scale worker=1`

I get this error :-

```
sh: 0: Can't open target/bin/worker
Process exited with status 127
State changed from up to crashed
```

My POM.xml is exactly same as it is in the tutorial with just few extra dependencies.

What is the issue and how can it be resloved ?

POM.xml :-

```
<dependencies>
....
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                        <name>worker</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

[image: Before running the mvn package]
[image: After running mvn package]

Comment: Heroku will build your app using Maven, not IntelliJ. Does `./mvnw compile` on your local machine create the `target/bin/worker` file?

Comment: Yes it does. I am actually using windows. So when i run `mvn package` in terminal, it builds the `target/bin/worker`. I switch to linux and then run `sh target/bin/worker` and it works. It executes the code perfectly. (I am doing this, because the worker.bat that is generated when run, says that the input command it too long so it cannot be run). But the main point is, when packaged using maven, the target folder is created containing `target/bin/worker` and `target/bin/worker.bat`.

Comment: @Malax So, I have more code and images to my question. ALso, `mvn compile` does not create `target/bin/worker`, but my POM.xml clearly mentions to package and the same was asked to do in the tutorial. Am i doing something wrong? I sure am new to maven. All guidance would be really appreaciated.

Comment: `mvn clean install` also generates the `target/bin/worker`